# Android WebView, view.capturePicture().getHeight() is 0

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

im working on Android 4.0. i have a WebView where i want to capture its screen.
i Override the WebViewClient onPageFinished as folow:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
Toast.makeText(finplan.this, "picture height "+picture.getHeight()+ " url "+url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in another procedure i called the loadUrl:

```
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
// this one works fine and picture.getHeight() is > 0

mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html"); 
// this one works, but the picture.getHeight() retrieved in onPageFinished is always 0
```

test.html is a any simple html file, i notice later that any loadUrl with "http//" works fine but dont works on 'file://'. Any help in this ???

Answer (score 0):

paste your .html file in assets folder of your project folder. and create an xml file in layout folder with the fol code: my.xml:

> ```
>    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>              android:id="@+id/webview"
>              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>           />
> ```

add fol code in activity

> ```
> setContentView(R.layout.my);
> WebView mWebView = null;
> mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
> mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
> mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html"); //new.html is html file name.
> ```